# Google Glass: Vignette for Videos?

Tags: google-glass

Newbie here. I just wrote an app/Glassware for Glass using GDK and I want to show it to others by making a video vignette (overlay of video from camera and glass display). I know picture vignettes are possible:

https://support.google.com/glass/answer/3405215?hl=en

But there's no mention of vignettes for videos. Anybody know if this feature will be implemented soon or if it's possible to implement this myself? Sorry, this is not a direct programming question but I don't know where else to ask. Thanks!

Cliff

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this at the moment, but you could technically take two video feeds and overlay them manually in an editor to get the same feeling. If you have questions like this you should really use the Google Glass Explorers Community Forum located here:

https://www.glass-community.com/

Comment: did the glass community go away? When I click "community" from google's main page, it says to go to stack overflow.

Comment: Go to https://google.com/myglass and click explorers on the top and that is the community. There is no Community on the main page as far as I know.

Comment: whoops, it's just restricted to glass owners